# How to allow 0 as argument in groovy?

Tags: groovy

Below is the code i am trying to run. This is a part of my service and the method is being called from the controller. Now, I want to allow all integer values >= 0 and avoid null values (which might occur when the controller passes only value of a or b).

```
int x = 10
int y = 10
boolean doSomething(int a, int b) {
    String logger = ""
    if(a >= 0 || a != null) {
        x = a
        logger += "Value of x is ${x}. "
    }
    if(b >= 0 || b != null) {
        y = b
        logger += "Value of y is ${y}. "
    }
    if(logger) {
        log.info logger
        return true
    }
    log.error "values not found"
    return false
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do this in groovy. The issue that i have been facing is that when only 1 value is passed, the other is updated to 0, which i do not want.

Comment: "I want to allow all integer values >= 0 and avoid null values" - can't you do exactly that?  i.e. `if (a >= 0 && a != null)`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth : nope, that doesnt work. Because only even one of the argument value is passed, the other is set to 0, which i do not want. _I'll update the question to clarify myself_

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  This (https://ideone.com/8op9IM) seems to be the behaviour you want, I think?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth : i've updated my question

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't see the issue.  For the code snippet above, can you explain what behaviour you were expecting, and what behaviour you actually observe?  (Or better yet, construct a [minimal test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to separate null from 0; don't count on groovy truth.

```
if (a != null && b != null && a >= 0 && b >= 0) {
    println "OK"
} else {
    println "Bad arguments"
}
```

Edits based on your question edits and subsequent comments:

- Your logic is a bit off; change your "||"s to "&&"s.  You want `a >= 0 AND a is not null"
- Change your input types to Integer so that they actually can be null
- Show how the params are being found for the action, if those two things do not solve your problem.

Comment: Is  there a way in grails to enforce the controller to pass both the values. if that is done, this works fine

Comment: Is your controller calling this code, or is this doSomething your controller action?  Also note that int is not quite the same as Integer and cannot truly be null; you may want to specify Integer if you want to strongly type your arguments.

Comment: its a controller action

Comment: Thanks a lot, changing the input type to Integer did the job. and '||' instead of '&&' was a typo.

thanks for the quick resolution

Comment: After changing to Integer, only a >= 0 is enough, as a != null is redundant now

Answer (score 2):

```
int x = 10
int y = 10
boolean doSomething(Integer a, Integer b) {
    String logger = ""
    if(a >= 0) {
        x = a
        logger += "Value of x is ${x}. "
    }
    if(b >= 0) {
        y = b
        logger += "Value of y is ${y}. "
    }
    if(logger) {
        log.info logger
        return true
    }
    log.error "values not found"
    return false
}
```

This is the final piece of code based on @Daniel's suggestion above. Here, only values >=0 will be accepted. Also, null values will be ignored.